# JQuery Find And Replace Query String in URL Based on HTML Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I would like to use jquery to change a particular value in the query string by doing a find and replace of that value based on what is selected from a dropdown option on the page. For example:

Let's say we have the following query string on the current page: ?field1=value1&field2=value2&archived=yes

With the dropdown options being:

- Non-Archived
- Archived

if someone selects "Non-Archived" the jquery function should do a find and replace on the current query string and set archived=yes to archived=no and then refresh the page.

Here's some code that I have now but it doesn't do a find and replace, it just takes what value I select from the dropdown and then changes the page based on the option value set in the drop down html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#dropdown").change(function(e){
window.location.href = jQuery("#dropdown").val();
});});
</script>


<select class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
<option value="#" selected="selected">Choose Type</option>
<option value="(set archived=no)">Non-Archived</option>
<option value="(set archived=yes)">Archived</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#dropdown").change(function (e) {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("archived") > -1) {
            window.location.href.replace(/(archived=yes|archived=no)/g, "archived=" + jQuery("#dropdown ").val());
        } else {
            window.location.href += "archived=" + jQuery("#dropdown ").val();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
<option value="#" selected="selected">Choose Type</option>
<option value="no">Non-Archived</option>
<option value="yes">Archived</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like this one appends the new query string value at the end of the query string? so I used that dropdown two times in a row, I would get a much larger query string (with additional fields and values) then where I started?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8aaR/2/)

```
var href="?field1=value1&field2=value2&archived=yes";
var testUrl = $(location).attr('href');
alert('Current URL = ' + testUrl);

jQuery("#dropdown").change(function(e){
    if($("#dropdown").val() == "(set archived=no)") {
        href = href.replace("archived=yes", "archived=no");
    } else if($("#dropdown").val() == "(set archived=yes)") {
        href = href.replace("archived=no", "archived=yes");
    }
    alert(href);
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. For the href value how do I get the current link of the page i'm on? It needs to be dynamic and not hard coded in. I would also like to current URL to refresh once one of the drop downs are selected.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use `$(location).attr('href')` to get the current URL. Then, you can use `window.location.href = 'new URL'` to refresh with the passed new URL.